# Find the inverse of a unit

Tags: ring-theory

I am trying to solve the following question:

> If $K$ is a field and $R=K[x]/(x^n)$.and $r=a_0+a_1x +\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ is an element in $R$ with $a_0\neq 0$, prove that $r$ is a unit and find its inverse.

To prove it is a unit, I know that $\gcd(r,x^n)=1$, so there exist $a,b \in K[x]$ such that $ra+x^nb=1$, $ra=1$ in $R$.

But to construct the inverse, and I know that $a_0$ has its inverse in K. Can someone give me some hint?

I also need to show that every zero divisor in $R$ is nilpotent. 
For nonzeros $a,b \in R$, if $ab=0$, then $x^n$ divides $ab$, does this imply that $a$ and $b$ both have no constant terms?

Comment: I think you need to tidy up which elements are in $R$ and which are in $K[X]$. And I don't understand your third paragraph.

Comment: Sorry about the mess. The equivalence class r inR has the representing element of the form $r=a_0+a_1x+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes so in your second para you need to make the distinction between the EA in $k[x]$ and the conclusion in $R$.

Comment: Thank you! That is why I got so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer to write $\xi$ for the image of $x$ in $K[x]/(x^n)$, just to be sure we're working in the right context.

What you want to prove is that $r=a_0+a_1\xi+\dots+a_{n-1}\xi^{n-1}$ is invertible in $R$.

Hints:

1. $a\xi^k$ is nilpotent, for every $a\in K$ and every positive integer $k$;
2. the sum of two nilpotent elements is nilpotent;
3. if $A$ is a commutative ring, $a\in A$ is invertible and $t\in A$ is nilpotent, then $a+t$ is invertible.

Finally, what are the nilpotent elements in $R$?

Comment: Thank you! Your hint is very clear!

Comment: How do I show that the zero divisors in R are nilpotent?

Comment: @user335468 $a_0+a_1\xi+\dots+a_{n-1}\xi^{n-1}$ can only be a zero divisor if $a_0=0$, because otherwise it is invertible.

Comment: Or you look at what that means about the representatives in $K[x]$: $g(x)h(x)$ is divisible by $x^n$, though neither $g(x)$ nor $h(x)$ is so divisible.

Answer (score 1):

Of course @egreg has given the best solution (and I gave it +1) by putting it all in a general context, but I can never resist the "idiot" answer to this question. It is clear from the Binomial Theorem that the inverse of $a_0+a_1x +\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+(x^n)$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k a_0^{-k-1}(a_1x +\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1})^k +(x^n)
$$
which happily (as we are trying to do algebra) is really a finite sum, every term after the $(n-1)$-th vanishing vanishing into $(x^n)$, as it has a factor $x^n$.

So not only is it a unit, we've calculated the inverse.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the sign, typed it up after a long day. Now repaired.

Comment: fyi - there was a still a typo, so I corrected it - I hope you don't mind...

Comment: No prob, though I usually suppress the $1$ in the $(-)^k$ thing.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to calculate its inverse